# HTML text location

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple question. Please bear with me, since I am new to HTML.
In my index.html, I have created a progress-bar, and now I want a "text" appears right after my progress bar, but it appears on the next line, rather than after the progress bar.

In my CSS file, I have a progress-bar class defined as follows:

```
.progressBar { 
   border:1px solid #aaa; 
   color:#fff; 
   width:295px; 
   height:5px;
}
.progress {
   background-color:#ff0000;
   height:5px;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Then, in my index.html, I have something like this:

```
<div class="progressBar" id="progressBar2"><div class="progress" id="progress2"></div></div>
```

And, I decided to put a text right after the progress-bar, and I did this:

```
<div class="progressBar" id="progressBar2"><div class="progress" id="progress2"></div></div><div id="myResults">HERE GOES MY TEXT</div>
```

But, how do I change it such that the text appears right after progress bar?

Thanks, 
--Rudy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp):

> **Floating Elements Next to Each Other**
>
> If you place several floating elements after each other, they will
>   float next to each other if there is room.
>
> The elements after the floating element will flow around it.
>
> The elements before the floating element will not be affected.
>
> If a div is floated to the left, a following text flows around it, to
>   the right

CSS:

```
 .progressBar { 
           border:1px solid #aaa; 
           color:#fff; 
           width:295px; 
           height:5px;
             **float:left;**
            background-color:blue;
        }
        .progress {
           background-color:#ff0000;
           height:5px;
           display:inline-block;
        }
```

Here is the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LA2Cw/1/)

Comment: Thanks guys, it sort of does the job, but how do I align it such that the "text" and "bar" appear on the same line. It looks like that the "bar" is sort of jumped a little higher, and it is not completely centered ?!?

Comment: I see that, but even though the text and the bar are on the same line, how can I make the bar just a little lower (center of the line)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can do this by the follow 2 methods.

The first way, you can try the follow code to let DIV not insert a line break before it, by adding a display attribute.

```
.progressBar { 
   border:1px solid #aaa; 
   color:#fff; 
   width:295px; 
   height:5px;
   display:inline-block;  ----> Added
}
.progress {
   background-color:#ff0000;
   height:5px;
   display:inline-block;
} 
#myResults {             ----> Added
   display:inline-block; ----> Added
}                        ----> Added
```

Please be aware of behavior of different display attribute in the follow URL:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

There are a bunch of value you can set for it.

---

Second, you can also use float attribute to set the browser to render div from left to right, without line break if there's any space for it left, using the follow code

```
.progressBar { 
   border:1px solid #aaa; 
   color:#fff; 
   width:295px; 
   height:5px;
   float:left;              -> Added
}
.progress {
   background-color:#ff0000;
   height:5px;
}
#myResults {                -> Added
  float:left;               -> Added
}                           -> Added
```

You can refer to the definition and description of float attribute here

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

---

I suggest you to dig into those materials I posted to have a better understanding of those concepts since those are really very basic for programing in HTML and it will make your work much faster if you can understand them first.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
   .progressBar { 
     border:1px solid #aaa; 
     color:#fff; 
     width:295px; 
     height:5px;
     float:left;   
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Align the `.progressbar` in `float:left`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9LCdw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the css as follows

### CSS

```
.progressBar {
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    color:#fff;
    width:295px;
    height:5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.progress {
    background-color:#ff0000;
    height:5px;
}
#myResults
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3qXhB/)**